# Grouping similar values in Matlab

Tags: matlab, grouping

If I have an array that contains the values `[6712, 7023, 7510, 7509, 6718, 7514, 7509, 6247]` and I want 4 groups of similar numbers so that the output is 4 matrices:

```
[6247]
[6712, 6718]
[7023]
[7510, 7509, 7514, 7509]
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the term you are looking for is **[clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis)**. For example, we can apply the [Kmeans algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) to group the data into 4 clusters:

```
X = [6712, 7023, 7510, 7509, 6718, 7514, 7509, 6247];
[IDX,C] = kmeans(X, 4, 'EmptyAction','singleton');
G = cell(4,1);
for i=1:4
    G{i} = X(IDX==i);
end
```

This is one of the result I get:

```
>> G{:}
ans =
        7510        7509        7514        7509
ans =
        7023
ans =
        6247
ans =
        6712        6718
```

Usually this works best with more points (also works for multidimensional data)

Comment: One serious problem with this approach is, that you need to be able to specify a prior the number of clusters. An quite different kind of approach would be to utilize the proximity, what OP actually suggested in one of the comments. Thanks

Comment: @eat: Kmeans is one partitioning-based algorithm. Other clustering algorithms exist such as [DBSCAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) and [mean-shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean-shift) which utilize density and similar notions to form the clusters (without specifying the number beforehand). I mentioned K-Means as an example simply because its probably the most well-known technique..

Comment: Well, with `DBSCAN` you need to specify 2 parameters and with `mean-shift` you need to specify initial guess. IMHO, both are less intuitive than just specifying a simple proximity criteria. FWIW, IMHO it's just a coincidence that the 4 clusters of 'k-means' corresponds with OP's requirement. Would `DBSCAN` and `mean-shift` fulfill the requirements as well? Thanks

Comment: @eat: I'm not trying to argue whose solution is best.. I tried to approach the problem in a more systematic and general way, instead of an ad-hoc solution (what if the numbers in the array change?). Clustering has the advantage that it tries to discover naturally-occurring groups in the data (in an unsupervised manner).

Comment: Well, I'm not either arguing whose solution is best (it's up to the OP). But frankly speaking, I disagree that unsupervised clustering, in general, will 'discover naturally-occurring groups in the data'. It's no way a magic oracle. I'll love to discuss this issue much more detailed manner, but I think our conversation should continue on the SO chat. (Just don't know how to transfer this thread there). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually, for your specific case, there's really no need for any kind of complicated (and quite incomprehensible) clustering procedure, nor any (seemingly simple looking) explicit sorting based solution.

Assuming now that your values, close to each other (more or less, like `abs(x- x_0)<= 50`) defines the groups (of interest), then why not just proceed with a very simple and straightforward manner.

Thus, by utilizing the 'most natural' [proximity](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/proximity) of your values to each other; you could simply proceed as follows:

```
>>> x= [6712 7023 7510 7509 6718 7514 7509 6247]; g= round(x/ 50)
g =
   134 140 150 150 134 150 150 125

>>> groups= {}; for g_u= unique(g), groups{end+ 1}= x(g_u== g); end
>>> groups
groups =
{
  [1,1] =  6247
  [1,2] =  6712 6718
  [1,3] =  7023
  [1,4] =  7510 7509 7514 7509
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "similar"? For instance, why is 6718 not similar to 7023? Do we mean "difference < N between consecutive ints in a group"?

If so, sort the array and then step through it, identifying boundaries where you need them (i.e., when the difference is too great). Then simply split off a new array.

Such as...

```
  GroupSimilar(values)
   1. result := list()
   2. values' := sort(values)
   3. temp := list()
   4. for i := 1 to |values'| - 1 do
   5.    if values'[i+1] - values'[i] <= diff then
   6.       temp.add(values'[i])
   7.    else
   8.        result.add(temp)
   9.        temp := list()
  10. return result
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Thomas. Yes, I mean that the difference between the integers in a "group" is less than N (in this case, let's say N = 50). I understand your method, but I am having trouble executing writing the code in Matlab.

Comment: Somebody else will need to help you with that. Also, if you want the (max - min) in a group to be less than N, that's a little different from what I'm doing... in mine, only adjacent numbers have to be less than N to be in a group. You can easily tweak mine to do it the other way, though. As for MATLAB syntax... somebody else will need to help you there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first decide what the criteria is for determining the boundaries of your groups. For example, you could set a threshold value of 50, so any values that differ from their nearest larger or smaller value are considered to be in a different group.

You can solve this in a vectorized way by first sorting the array using the function [SORT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sort.html), then finding the indices into the sorted array where the differences between neighboring values are greater than your threshold (i.e. where the group boundaries are) using the functions [DIFF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/diff.html) and [FIND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/find.html). Taking the differences between these indices (again using the function [DIFF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/diff.html)) gives you a vector of sizes for each group, which can be used to break the sorted array into a cell array using the function [MAT2CELL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mat2cell.html). Here's what the code would look like:

```
threshold = 50;
array = [6712 7023 7510 7509 6718 7514 7509 6247];
sortedArray = sort(array);
nPerGroup = diff(find([1 (diff(sortedArray) > threshold) 1]));
groupArray = mat2cell(sortedArray,1,nPerGroup);
```

And `groupArray` will be a 1-by-4 cell array where each cell contains a set of values for a group. Here are the contents of `groupArray` for the above example:

```
>> groupArray{:}

ans =

        6247

ans =

        6712        6718

ans =

        7023

ans =

        7509        7509        7510        7514
```